# search dataframe for a keyword in any column and get the rows

Tags: python, search, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have  a dataframe which I wish to get a subset by checking for the presence of  a keyword across all columns in all rows one by one.
Here is the snippet:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('TEST')).any()
```

but because not all column values are of string type  and so it throws error:

> AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values

Any help is  appreciated.

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 6):

Flying blind without an example here, but how about:

`df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('TEST').any(), axis=1)`

So, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['0.0', 'Hello', 'Goodbye'], (12, 3)))
df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('Hello').any(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without data it is complicated, but I try use numpy function [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and list comprehension:

```
print df
       A      B          D   E
0      A  TEST1 2014-04-08   8
1      B  TEST2 2014-05-08   7
2      B      C 2014-05-08  15
3      B  TEST3 2014-05-08   1
4  TESTA      A 2014-04-08   6
5      A  TEST5 2014-04-08   1
```

**Mask subset with columns with string data**:

```
 mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains("TEST") for col in ['A', 'B']])
 print mask
 [[False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False False]
 [False  True]
 [ True False]
 [False  True]]
print df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
       A      B          D  E
0      A  TEST1 2014-04-08  8
1      B  TEST2 2014-05-08  7
3      B  TEST3 2014-05-08  1
4  TESTA      A 2014-04-08  6
5      A  TEST5 2014-04-08  1
```

**Mask subset with excluded columns with not string data**:

```
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains("TEST") for col in df if col not in ['D', 'E']])
print mask
[[False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False False]
 [False  True]
 [ True False]
 [False  True]]
print df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
       A      B          D  E
0      A  TEST1 2014-04-08  8
1      B  TEST2 2014-05-08  7
3      B  TEST3 2014-05-08  1
4  TESTA      A 2014-04-08  6
5      A  TEST5 2014-04-08  1
```