# pandas DF with 1 or more columns to search for keywords, keywords to search for in a second DF; case insensitive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As stated in title, I have a dataframe (let's call this df1) that is similar to this:

| Col A | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | Dog |
| 00002 | dogs |
| 00003 | cat |
| 00004 | cats |
| 00005 | hooman |

I have a list of keywords I want to search, in a second dataframe, df2:

| Keyword |
| --- |
| dog |
| cats |
| bird |

How do I identify all records in df1 that has at least one keyword match from df2, and the final outcome is a dataframe (new or add to df1) that lists all the columns in df1 + the matched keyword? On top of that... ideally case insensitive, and the keyword list entry "dog" would help me also find "dogs" from df1?

Sample Expected Output:

| Col A | Desc | Matched Keyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Dog | dog |
| 00002 | dogs | dog |
| 00003 | cat |  |
| 00004 | cats | cats |
| 00005 | hooman |  |

I've searched for some time in this site, here are a few other ones I have tried to follow but none of them actually worked. I always get nothing matched.

[search dataframe for a keyword in any column and get the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354390/search-dataframe-for-a-keyword-in-any-column-and-get-the-rows)
[value matching between two DataFrames using pandas in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131193/value-matching-between-two-dataframes-using-pandas-in-python)
[searching if anyone of word is present in the another column of a dataframe or in another data frame using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055007/searching-if-anyone-of-word-is-present-in-the-another-column-of-a-dataframe-or-i)
[How to search for a keyword in different pandas dataframe and update or create a new column with matching keyword in parent DF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69389212/how-to-search-for-a-keyword-in-different-pandas-dataframe-and-update-or-create-a)

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: please provide the expected output for clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
from typing import List

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["0001","0002","0003","0004","0005"], 'values':["dogs","cat","Dog","cats","hooman"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Keywords": ['dog','cat','bird']})

def find_string_in_substring(value:str, list_of_strings: List[str]):
    for sub_value in list_of_strings:
        if value.lower() in sub_value.lower() or sub_value.lower() in value.lower():
            return sub_value
    return False

df1["keyword_from_df2"] = df1["values"].apply(lambda x : find_string_in_substring(x,df2['Keywords'].tolist()))
df1
```

The logic is pretty straight forward, hope it is good enough, if not I will try to help better!

Comment: thanks @eldar-shua! I just ran it but have a question - if nothing is found, is the column filled with a string "False" or is it boolean? I'm trying to filter and validate the results, when I try to filter False as string 

df1[df1['Matched Keywords'] != "False", I see records are filtered by instead of "not equal", it gave me all the "False"? If I treat that as boolean, nothing returned.

Or did I do something as I am not too familiar with Python (still).

Comment: you are welcome!
df1[df1["keyword_from_df2"] != False] and not "False"

Comment: It would be good if you would mark my answer as correct, thank you

Comment: hmm... now that actually seem that no match was found... but I made sure it does have a match. maybe something else I am missing

Comment: also @eldar-shua I am not familiar with the lambda thing - what is x referring to?